# Mailboxer Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I'm currently trying to find a way to send private messages between users. I found the mailboxer gem. I'm new to rails and have not been able to successfully send a message. has anyone been able to use this gem for their applications using Rails 4?

Any help will be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: what errors did you get when sending fails? I have used it in Rails 4 without issues.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am still a bit confused about setting it up. As I said I'm still a rookie. I installed the gem without any problem. I followed all the instructions listed on the github page. I then created a conversations folder that would include displayinbox, dispaysent, NewMessage etc. I think I have the right idea, but just don't know how to actually set up the views. Not sure if this explains my issue. How did you set it up for your app?  I am using devise to register users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hello

Please use latest version of [mailboxer](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer).

It works with Rails 4.0, 4.1 also.

IF you still facing errors , please describe here.

Thank you

[Mailboxer-app](https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app)

Comment: Hi Mehul, thanks for the reply. I am still a bit confused about setting it up. As I said I'm still a rookie. I installed the gem without any problem. I followed all the instructions listed on the github page. I then created a conversations folder that would include displayinbox, dispaysent, NewMessage etc. I think I have the right idea, but just don't know how to actually set up the views. Not sure if this explains my issue. How did you set it up for your app?  I am using devise to register users.

Comment: @Ronaldoh1 - I have added sample example application, It will help you , please let me know if you still face errors. Conversations & messages folder should be in your view directory

Comment: Hey than so much Mehul - I've been a bit MIA lately but I'm back. I will let you know if i run into problems.  Thank you!